# How can I change the background color of the navigation bar - Vaadin

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I'm using the class `AppLayout` in Vaadin. I wonder how I can change the background color in the navigation bar.

I know how to add CSS style in Vaadin, but I have trouble to access the navigation class.

Here is my code. As you see, I'm always using the method `setClassName`. But where can I find that method for the navigation bar?

```
@Viewport("width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes, viewport-fit=cover")
@PWA(name = "Hemsida", shortName = "Hem")
@Route("")
@CssImport("./CSS/MainView.css")
public class MainView extends AppLayout {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MainView() {

        // Image bar
        Image barImage = new Image("img/cropped-logo_liggande_rod.png", "Spektrakon Logo");
        barImage.setClassName("barImage");

        // Drawer
        DrawerToggle drawerToggle = new DrawerToggle();
        drawerToggle.setClassName("drawerToggle");


        addToNavbar(barImage, drawerToggle);


        Tabs tabs = new Tabs(new Tab("Hem"), new Tab("Produktutveckling"), new Tab("Industriell Design"), new Tab("System"), new Tab("Kvalitet"), new Tab("Om oss"), new Tab("Intrenet"));
        tabs.setOrientation(Tabs.Orientation.VERTICAL);
        addToDrawer(tabs);
    }

}
```

Comment: If the navbar is a child component of AppLayout, you should be able to use the style you're adding to AppLayout to get a handle on the navbar

Comment: @Jay I have tried, but cannot find any handle.

Comment: If you check the DOM, is navbar a child div?

Comment: @Jay DOM? If I check the API, so no, the navbar is not a child div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Styling part](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-app-layout/html-api/elements/Vaadin.AppLayoutElement) you can see there is a `navbar` part. You can use it to style the navbar of a AppLayout

---

if `navbarStyles.css` has:

```
[part~="navbar"]{
    background-color: red;
}
```

And imported to the view with :
`@CssImport(value= "./styles/navbarStyles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-app-layout")`, background color is changed

---

A complete example with using `theme` to distinguish from other `AppLayout`'s

```java
@Route("")
@CssImport(value= "./styles/navbarStyles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-app-layout")
public class AppLayoutPictures extends AppLayout {

    public AppLayoutPictures(){
        setPrimarySection(AppLayout.Section.DRAWER);
        Image img = new Image("https://i.imgur.com/GPpnszs.png", "Vaadin Logo");
        img.setHeight("44px");
        addToNavbar(new DrawerToggle(), img);
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs(new Tab("Home"), new Tab("About"));
        tabs.setOrientation(Tabs.Orientation.VERTICAL);
        addToDrawer(tabs);
       //Set to AppLayout, propageted to `parts`
        getElement().setAttribute("theme","appLayout");
    }
```

`navbarStyles.css`

```css
:host([theme~="appLayout"]) [part~="navbar"]{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: Great! Does it need to be `navbarStyles.css`?

Comment: No, you can rename it to anything you want as long as it's a css file :)

Comment: You are using V14? and where you have put the css file? under what repo?

Comment: Also, can your post your style file as well?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson You are missing from `@CssImport("./CSS/MainView.css")` a `themeFor = "vaadin-app-layout"`. This should solve it :)

Comment: Yes! 14. I cannot have "vaadin-app-layout". It will mess up the rest of the view. https://pastebin.com/Gy1fQHy4

Comment: What do you mean by `mess up the rest`? Anyway, if you want to style navbar of applayout, you would need to do it via `part` as shown in my example. This is because of shadow dom and its encapsulation of styles

Comment: In your css file there is no snippet from my example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205945/discussion-between-anasmi-and-daniel-martensson).